# NGINX 502 Bad Gateway - 2 Spring apps - 1 works, 1 doesn't

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a very simple NGINX configuration for two endpoints, for two different Spring Boot apps.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name somedomain.io;

        location ^~ /search {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/search$is_args$args;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        }

        location = /contact_form {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:7080/contact_form;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        }
}
```

Location `search` is for one Spring application (does not work) and location `contact_form` for another (works fine).

When I attempt to hit `search` it doesn't pass the request to my application and instead throws the following response.

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>502 Bad Gateway</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="white">
    <center>
        <h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1>
    </center>
    <hr>
    <center>nginx/1.14.1</center>
</body>

</html>
```

The url I'm attempting to hit is `http://somedomain.io/search?area=London`.

Error log prints the following.

> 2020/04/04 18:33:27 [error] 31578#0: *2801 no resolver defined to resolve localhost, client: 90.248.234.209, server: somedomain.io, request: "GET /search?area=London HTTP/1.1", host: "somedomain.io"

Both apps work fine when ran on a local environment.

Any ideas on where the problem may be?

Comment: Try: `proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;`

Comment: That solved it, thank you